# Trying to add more users to HTML table

Tags: php, html

I'm having trouble with a basic "Appointment System". Every time i submit a new user data, the old user data gets overwritten. It should allow multiple users to input name, address, and then show it on the HTML Table. I've also attached a screenshot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gLz3.png)

```
<html>
<h1> Welcome to Doctor Scheduler </h1>
<body>

Please enter your details so we can fit you in.


<form action = "" method="post">
<label for="name">Name:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
<label for="address">Address:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="address" name="address"><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="status" name="status" value="New">
<label for="status">Check if you are a new patient</label><br><br>

<label for="appt">Choose a time for your meeting:</label>

<input type="time" id="appt" name="appt"
       min="06:00" max="18:00" required></br>

Office hours are 6am to 6pm<br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>


<?php


    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" and isset($_POST['buttonSubmit']))
    {
        $array =
        $temp = array('Name'=>$_POST['name'], 'Address'=>$_POST['address'],'Status'=>$_POST['status'], 'TimeSlot'=>$_POST['appt']);
        array_push($array, $temp);

        write_array($array);
        echo new_table($array);
    }

    function new_table($array)
    {
    echo '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="2">';

    foreach($array as $temp) { 
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $temp['Name'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $temp['Address'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $temp['Status'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $temp['TimeSlot'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}
    function write_array($array)
    {
        /*$string = serialize($array);
        $fn = 'patients.txt';
        $fh = fopen($fn, 'w');
        fwrite($fh, $string);
        fclose($fh);*/

        $fp = fopen('patients.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, print_r($array, TRUE));
        fclose($fp);
    }
?>

</html>
```

Comment: you need to either save it to a session, or  to a database. It looks like you are saving it to a file, instead of database. So if you are saving it to a file, to you need to read the file, in everytime the page loads.

Comment: Everytime you submit your form, `php` will "override" you var on `$temp = array(...)`, it is "normal", it is doing what you just coded... You need to save the data somewhere, maybe using `$_SESSION`, a DataBase, a File, etc...